# Xscreensaver cnnot displaz GLSchool

Tags: nvidia, screensaver

Running Ubuntu 16.04, 64-bit AMD, just updated to NVIDIA driver 375.39, and thereafter lost the ability to display Xcrnsaver's "GLSchool" (and other GL screensaver images.) The settings|screensaver tool still shows the entiry, but pegs it as "no preview available", and indeed, when screen goes into saver mode it is just black.

I suppose I can liv without those cute fish, but fear the problem portends something deeper.

Answer (score 1):

As suspected, I found other programs that didn't display. I had reinstalled xscreensaver plus data. Mostly a reboot was the therapeutic step (the update did not specify that a reboot was needed.)
All's well that ends well.